# Excel "Find & Select" replacing commas with a new line inserts many new lines instead of one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in the form of `{a,b,c,d}` but I like to convert it to

```
{a
b
c
d}
```

When I use Excel "Find & Select" and try to replace comma with new line (Ctrl-J) it often times replaces instead of one new line MANY new lines. This sometimes does not happen if I create new spreadsheet on the first tab, but it happens more often than not. How do I avoid this bug?

Maybe if I cannot avoid this bug there is a way to remove all those extra new lines and just leave a single new line?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you certain there are more than three `CR`? The only way I can even reproduce the appearance of what you show, after doing the find/replace as you did, is by enlarging the row and selecting `distributed` or `justify` for the vertical alignment.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue either. What do these extra new lines look like? Are these lines blank or not? Maybe you could  try to set cells as "Wrap text" format, adjust these cells to a long and narrow shape. The result looks like the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90h0.jpg).

Comment: @Emily Yeah I have no idea why my Excel bugs, it was working fine for some time and then this behavior started ...

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I see,  Yeah I have no idea why my Excel bugs, it was working fine for some time and then this behavior started ...

Comment: it seems like a bug that might not be easily reproducible, so if someone knows a workaround to remove extra new lines and leave only single new line, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that the appearance is due to multiple new lines, I would start Excel in safe mode and try to repeat the operation. It may be that something that is installed -an add in? - is messing up the process. Then it is a matter of elimination.